# scp between two remote hosts from my (third) pc

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, shell, scp

I have two remote hosts.
host1-> 10.3.0.1
host2-> 10.3.0.2
Both run an ssh server.

The ssh server listens on port 22 in host1 and on port 6969 in host2.
Now, using my local machine, I need to copy something from host1 to host2 without logging into either host1 or host2 via ssh. Something like,

```
scp user@10.3.0.1:/path/to/file user@10.3.0.2/path/to/file
```

How can I do this, please note that the two hosts use different ports for ssh.

Comment: Are you asking if you can transfer from a remote host to a remote host, or are you asking how to do it without having to supply a password?

Comment: While the `-P` flag exists to specify the port to use, in case of remote-to-remote transfer, ssh as no defined behaviour on how to specify per-host port...

Answer (score 325):

In the past, the way in which `scp` worked, when called (**naively**) to copy files between remote systems, was very inconvenient: if you wrote, for instance

```
    scp user1@remote1:/home/user1/file1.txt user2@remote2:/home/user2/file1.txt
```

`scp` would first open an `ssh` session on remote1, and then it would run `scp` from there to remote2. For this to work, you would have to set up the authorization credentials for remote2 on remote1.

The modern way to do it, instead, ("modern" because it was implemented only a few years ago, and perhaps not everybody has a `-3`-capable `scp`) requires two steps.  The first necessary step is to use `~/.ssh/config` to set up all options for the connection to both remote1 and remote2, as follows:

```
    Host remote1.example.org
    Port 2222
    IdentityFile /path/to/host1-id_rsa

    Host remote2.example.org
    Port 6969
    IdentityFile /path/to/host2-id_rsa
```

This way it becomes  possible to pass all necessary options to the command **without ambiguities**: for instance, if we had said on the CLI *use port 2222* without the above configuration, it would have been unclear whether we were referring to *remote1* or to *remote2*, and likewise for the file containing the cryptgraphic keys. This way the CLI remains tidy and simple.

Secondly, use the `-3` option, as follows:

```
    scp -3 user1@remote1:/home/user1/file1.txt user2@remote2:/home/user2/file1.txt
```

The `-3` option instructs `scp` to route traffic through the PC on which the command is issued, even though it is a 3rd party to the transfer. This way, authorization credentials must  reside only on the issuing PC, the third party.

Comment: For future reference: If you copy a file between two hosts that share an identity file (like an EC2 instance), then you don't need the config file. One -i argument is sufficient to connect to both hosts.

Comment: Also worth noting, for Google Compute Engine, there is support for adding to your `~/.ssh/config` file: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/ but I don't think that AWS has the same support

Comment: Since you won't see the output as you normally do, a tip is to enable the verbose mode with `-v`.

Comment: This post clearly says: "routing the traffic through the third PC", but I, at least, didn't parse it to mean: "This will be extremely slow". If that's what you need you'll have to set up remote1 with the relevant credentials. It's a one-off thing though, then it'll work.

Comment: How can I use sshpass here? I need to pass in the password for both servers.

Comment: @FonsMA quite often, it's better to be slower than to give credentials to servers that shouldn't have them.

Answer (score 46):

The source and target can be specified as a URI in the form scp://[user@]host[:port][/path]

so you can run:

```
scp -3 scp://user@10.3.0.1:22/path/to/file scp://user@10.3.0.2:6969/path/to/file
```

Comment: **This is THE answer.** Please note that the path starts after the first `/`, so if you want an absolute path you'll put `//` after the port (eg. `scp://user@10.3.0.1:22//etc/*`), or it would be interpreted as local to user's home. You can use `-v` to see what files are being transferred, very useful when using wildcards.

Comment: @Vanni, words do not describe how much your simple comment `o if you want an absolute path you'll put // after the port (eg. scp://user@10.3.0.1:22//etc/*), or it would be interpreted as local to user's home` just helped....I've wasted nearly a complete day pulling my hair out because of precisely that. I must have read the rest of the internet about SCP before finding this...Thanks!!

Comment: @Chris I'm glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 8):

Last time I tried this,  scp wasn't able to do that. Your command line looks okay. This workaround will work:

```
ssh -p port_on_machine1 user@machine1 "cat /path/to/file/one"|ssh -p port_on_machine2 user@machine2 "cat >/path/to/file/two"
```

Comment: my scp man page says "Copies between two remote hosts are also permitted."

Comment: Thanks, it is good to hear. To scp you can give a -P flag (it was written by some BSD people, this because its argument handling is so tragic :-( ), but it seems you can't specify different ports on the remote hosts. I am sorry, but I think, only this workaround lefts (or there are a lot of trickier solutions, using ssh but avoiding scp - for example, sftpfs, but they are not the simplest). I extended my workaround with the port settings.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I was doing a remote to remote copy, withouth the `-3` argument.
The port given with the '-P' parameter works with the 1st server, but port 22 is used with the 2nd one.

```
ssh -P 1234 user@server1.mydomain.com user@server2.otherdomain.com
```

The solution is to edit the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file in `server1` and add these lines:

```
Host *.otherdomain.com
   Port  1234
```

In this way, the port 1234 is used for both of them.  It could be different too.

This solution has better throughput than previous solutions, because communitation is direct.

Comment: perez is there a way to achieve scp through two different ports for the two different remote machines from the comman line?

Answer (score 3):

I know, this topic is a few years old, but OpenSSH 8.4 (released 2020-09-27) added agent forwarding to scp and sftp.

Now it's possible to copy a file from one remote to another, without routing through your local machine or provide credentials on the first host, to authenticate against the second host.

```
scp -A user1@remote1:/home/user1/file1.txt user2@remote2:/home/user2/file1.txt
```

**Warning!** Using agent forwarding is a security issue, when the first host is compromised or when you are affected from a mitm attack.

Answer (score 0):

You can also provide the `SOURCE` and `DESTINATION` identity files in the CLI options `-o IdentityFile` rather than setting these up in .ssh/config. This is handy for e.g. a one-off `-3` copy

```
scp -3 -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/source.key -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/dest.key source-user@example.com:/path/to/file dest-user@destination.com:/dest/location/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have .ssh/config on your local machine properly set up for two remote servers, you can do:

scp -3 server1:~/path_file server2:~/path_file

Comment: What is the added value of your answer regarding other answers?

Comment: Brevity and simplicity.

Comment: *Too brief*, and *too simple* are Unhelpful.

Comment: "All generalizations are bad", right?