# How to scp across two ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, scp

I have three computers HOME, WORK and SERVER and I am connected from HOME to SERVER by:

```
ssh -t <WORKusername>@<WORK> ssh -p23456 <SERVERusername>@localhost
```

I need to **transfer the file from HOME to SERVER**  but I am not able to leave the file in **WORK**

Also I would need to **transfer a file from the SERVER to HOME** after processing it, how do i do it?

I have took a look at https://serverfault.com/questions/37629/how-do-i-do-multihop-scp-transfers and [scp between two remote hosts from my (third) pc](https://superuser.com/questions/686394/scp-between-two-remote-hosts-from-my-local) but i am unable to change the ssh config on the **HOME** machine

And i've tried this but i got nowhere:

```
$ scp -o ProxyCommand="ssh <WORKusername>@<WORK> nc localhost" ASPEC.zip <SERVERusername>@localhost:~/
<WORKusername>@<WORK>'s password: 
This is nc from the netcat-openbsd package. An alternative nc is available
in the netcat-traditional package.
usage: nc [-46DdhklnrStUuvzC] [-i interval] [-P proxy_username] [-p source_port]
      [-s source_ip_address] [-T ToS] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_protocol]
      [-x proxy_address[:port]] [hostname] [port[s]]
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
lost connection
```

I've also tried the following but this is the reverse to transfer file from SERVER -> HOME:

```
ssh -t <WORKusername>@<WORK> "ssh -p 23456 <SERVERusername>@localhost \"cat file.zip\""
```

I've also tried tar but it didn't work:

```
tar c file.zip | ssh -t <WORKusername>@<WORK> "ssh -p 23456  <SERVERusername>@localhost | tar x"
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
<WORKusername>@<WORK>'s password: 
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Then I tried:

```
# From home:
$ ssh -L 23456:<SERVERusername>@localhost:22 <WORKusername>@<WORK>

# After ssh, in WORK:
$ ssh -p 23456 <SERVERusername>@localhost

# From home:
$ scp -P file.zip <SERVERusername>@localhost:~/
```

And i got these error when i give the scp command,

```
# on WORK terminal:
channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed

# on SERVER terminal:
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
lost connection
```

I've also tried rsync but it didn't work:

```
rsync -e "ssh -A -t <WORKusername>@<WORK>e ssh -p23456 <SERVERusername>@localhost" file.zip :~/
```

**How can I scp from HOME to transfer a file to SERVER?**

**And also from SERVER to HOME?**

Comment: Did you try to scp from home to work and then from work to server? Something like this (from head; might not work out of the box): `scp <localfile> <workusername>@<work>:/tmp/<filename> && ssh -t <WORKusername>@<WORK> scp -P23456 /tmp/<filename> <serveruser>@localhost:/<somedirectoryontheserver>` So first you scp it to your work and then you give (via ssh) the command to your work computer to scp it further to the server. It puzzles me though why you connect to server via localhost. Is is a virtual server on your work computer? If it works I'll transfer it to the answer section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use  this:

```
scp -P SERVERPORT -o 'ProxyCommand ssh -p WORKPORT WORKUSER@WORK nc %h %p 2>/dev/null' localfile SERVERUSER@SERVER:remotefile
```

`ProxyCommand` create the proxy on WORK host that connected to SERVER:SERVERPORT (see [nc](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/nc.1?query=nc)).
`%h` and `%p` are ssh variables - target host and port respectively.

Comment: thanks it works but how do i do the reverse from SERVER to HOME?

Comment: same way, just swap `SERVERUSER@SERVER:remotefile` and `localfile`, like: `scp -P SERVERPORT -o 'ProxyCommand ssh -p WORKPORT WORKUSER@WORK nc %h %p 2>/dev/null' SERVERUSER@SERVER:remotefile localfile`

Comment: i'm getting `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host` when transferring from HOME to SERVER =(

Comment: ah typo errrors, now it works, woohoo!! thanks a million!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
cat localfile | ssh <WORKusername>@<WORK> "ssh -p23456 <SERVERusername>@localhost 'cat > remotefile'"
```