# transfer files from remote-server to local-host via jump-host when port-forwarding is administratively inhibited

Tags: linux, ssh, security, rsync, tar

a valid however sometimes hindering policy at work is that remote server ports are not available in user space.

I only found the following solutions which (probably, as I didn't try them all) won't work.

- [Rsync files via intermediate host](https://superuser.com/questions/1115715/rsync-files-via-intermediate-host)
- [How to scp across two ssh](https://superuser.com/questions/798903/how-to-scp-across-two-ssh)

e.g. when using rsync with -e and ssh -J it results in

```
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
stdio forwarding failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [Receiver=3.1.2]
```

so i need a way that will not require a port but only use stdin

Answer (score 0):

for downloading though ssh terminal

```
ssh -ACq USER@JUMP-HOST 'ssh -ACq USER2@REMOTE-HOST "tar --warning=none -cC ~/DIRECTORY  ./FILES"' | tar -xv
```

- connection to jump host and then to remote host
- the connection is facilitated through keys
- tar compression does not make sense because the connections are compressed already
- [shell explanation](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ssh%20-ACq%20USER%40JUMP-HOST%20%27ssh%20-ACq%20USER2%40REMOTE-HOST%20%22tar%20--warning%3Dnone%20-cC%20%7E%2FDIRECTORY%20%20.%2FFILES%22%27%20%7C%20tar%20-xv)

for uploading

```
tar -c ./FILES | ssh -ACq USER@JUMP-HOST 'ssh -ACq USER2@REMOTE-HOST "tar -xvC ~/DIRECTORY"'
```